# how to close contact list after pick (android)

Tags: android, android-contacts, forceclose

****im trying to do n sms app and im using this code to pick some data from contact my 
probleam is when im closing my app the contact list is still opend.. how can i close it?**

**is there any way to pick the data and force close the contact list activity?**

**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    TextView a1,a2;
    EditText contact,message;
    Button send;
    String name,phoneNumber;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initilaize();
    }
    public void initilaize(){
        a1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVContact);
        a2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tVMessage);
        contact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTContact);
        message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTMessage);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        name ="";
        phoneNumber="";

        contact.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    try {
                        String id = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
                        Cursor phoneCur = getContentResolver()
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);

                        final ArrayList<String> phonesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        while (phoneCur.moveToNext()) {
                            // This would allow you get several phone addresses
                            // if the phone addresses were stored in an array
                            String phone = phoneCur
                                    .getString(phoneCur
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
                            phonesList.add(phone);
                        }
                        phoneCur.close();
                        //
                        String name="";
                        Cursor c =  managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);  
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {  
                            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        }
                        c.close();


                            //

                        if (phonesList.size() == 0) {

                        } else{
                           phoneNumber = phonesList.get(0);
                           this.name = name;
                           contact.setText(name);
                        }          } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("FILES", "Failed to get phone data", e);

                     }
                }   

            }





    }
    public boolean onTouch1(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.eTContact:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.button1:{


        }
        }   
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: copy paste your code from the method `onTouch1()` to `onTouch()` and delete `onTouch1()`. NB you can simply use `onClickListener` instead of `onTouchListener`

Comment: tanks! the onClick works! but the onTouch dosn't even after copy paste and the deletion of onTouch1